# Error in loading a data to neo4j in case statement in cypher query

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

try to upload `CSV` data with a case statement in the query, but the following error appears:

**cypher:**

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///test.csv' as line
MATCH(a:test_t{tid:line.pid})
CASE
  WHEN line.key !='NA' THEN
    WITH split(line.key,",") as name
    UNWIND name as x
    MERGE(k:test_key{key_term:toLower(x)})
    MERGE(a)-[:contains]->(k)
END
```

**Error**

> Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Invalid input 'S': expected 'l/L' (line 5, column 3 (offset: 137))
>       "CASE"

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `CASE` incorrectly. You cannot have update clauses inside of a CASE statement. Instead you can use a `WHERE` clause to filter the rows of the file. For instance, adding `WHERE line.key != 'NA'` while processing the file befor you move onto the update will work. Something like this should fit the bill.

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///test.csv' as line
MATCH (a:test_t {tid: line.pid})
WITH line
WHERE line.key <> 'NA' 
WITH split(line.key, ",") as name
UNWIND name as x
MERGE (k:test_key {key_term: toLower(x)})
MERGE (a)-[:contains]->(k)
```

It looks like,from your logic you could even move the test up above the `MATCH`. So this might be better (fewer unecessary matches).

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///test.csv' as line
WITH line
WHERE line.key <> 'NA' 
MATCH (a:test_t {tid: line.pid})
WITH split(line.key, ",") as name
UNWIND name as x
MERGE (k:test_key {key_term: toLower(x)})
MERGE (a)-[:contains]->(k)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `CASE` clause does not support embedding other Cypher clauses (but it can invoke functions). In fact, a `CASE` clause is not actually needed for your use case.

This query should work (the `:auto` at the beginning is needed in neo4j 4.0+):

```
:auto USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///test.csv' as line FIELDTERMINATOR ';'
WITH line
WHERE line.key <> 'NA'
MATCH (a:test_t {tid: line.pid})
UNWIND split(line.key, ',') as x
MERGE (k:test_key {key_term: TOLOWER(x)})
MERGE (a)-[:contains]->(k)
```

This query filters out all unwanted `line`s as soon as they are obtained from the file. Reducing the number of rows of data being worked on as early as possible is good practice.

Also, you have a second issue. Your data file cannot use the comma as both the (default) field terminator AND as the delimiter between your `x` values.

To resolve this ambiguity, the above query chose to use the `FIELDTERMINATOR ';'` option to specify that the ";" character will be used as the field terminator. A sample data file would look like this:

```
pid;key
123;NA
234;Foo,Bar
345;Bar,Baz
456;NA
567;Baz
```